# Mark or highlight part of a text inside a div with watir

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

How can I select or mark part of a text inside the content of a div using watir? I tried to `focus` and `double_click`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work:

```
require "watir-webdriver/extensions/select_text"
browser.div(id: "select").select_text "text"
```

Comment: Worked greatly! Thanks Željko.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the *flash* method, for instance...

```
browser=Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto('http://example.com')
browser.div(:id => 'example').p.flash
```

There is no official highlight method, but flash works for most of what I must use.